# QWidget::save/restoreGeometry loses window size if maximized - bug or feature?

Tags: qt, window, geometry

I am writing Qt (4.8.1 on Ubuntu 12.04) application that stores it's main window geometry between sessions. I noticed that if widget is maximized, qt is not storing it's non-maximized geometry. Obviously I would like my application to return to it's non-maximized size just the same if it was closed/started since last maximization. In

1. Main window is not maximized and has geometry X;
2. maximize main window;
3. save window geometry (using QWidget::saveGeometry) to config file;
4. close my application;
5. start it again;
6. load geometry from config file
7. Restore (un-maximize? ;)

After step 6 window gets maximized (as expected), but after step 7 it returns to some internal default size (i. e. one set while designing form in QtCreator), not to last non-maximized geometry X.

Is this desired behavior? Or is it impossible/difficult to implement inside qt?

Is it because when maximized, the non maximized size is remembered by window manager and not qt (at least on linux)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to save the geometry when the window is maximized to begin-with.

To get your required functionality just modify your steps as follows:

1. Main window is not maximized and has geometry X;
2. Save Geometry X also left-top position of window as `QPoint` Y
3. maximize main window;
4. Do **NOT** save geometry (You can figure if window state is maximized using `QWidget::isMaximized()` before saving to config file). Save a new `isMaximised` state value to config file instead.
5. close my application;
6. start it again;
7. Before you call `window->show()` apply a `window->resize(lastQSizeSavedinSettingsofNonMaximisedState)` and a `window->move(lastQPointSavedinSettingsofNonMaximisedState)`
8. Now check the `isMaximised` state value from config and if true, just call [QWidget::showMaximized()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#showMaximized) else just `QWidget::show()`
9. Now when you restore window size, you should have your desired functionality :)

Something to keep in mind when working with window size/states.

Always provide a fallback geometry and position in-case the last saved positions are out of bounds when the application is started and values you try to restore are not within the screen bounds anymore. (This helps catering for cases where someone changes resolution / monitor count / monitor position / virtual desktops)

Comment: That would mean that I would have to track my widows size/position all the time - on every resize. Point 3 is not done by my code but simply by user clicking maximize button on window bar. In fact at current stage of development all steps I listed are activated by user separately. Anyway - this is not the point of my question - I know my way around widget geometry and controlling it - but I thought `QWidget::saveGeometry` exists exactly to free my from worrying about it at all - and since I have to write geometry saving/restoring anyway, does it mean it is not serving it's purpose (is bugged)?

Comment: QWidget.cpp does indeed try to restore normalGeometry and frameGeometry with windowStates in the QByteArray argument for QWidget::restoreGeometry(...). I'd say raise a QT Bug for this if it does not work for you cos as in another bug https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-21371 the last but 6th comment indicates normalGeometry gets reset when going from fullscreen/maximised to normal state and this did not happen in Qt 4.7. As i guess you know there are a few workarounds for it. Also not sure if Qt 5 resolved it. It's a case of Qt trying to do something and not doing it correct = bug

Answer (score 1):

> 4. Do NOT save geometry (You can figure if window state is maximized using QWidget::isMaximized() before saving to config file). Save a new isMaximised state value to config file instead.

Another problem here is: A window will not just be maximized/minimized based on its position on the screen but based on where the greater part of the window is. If 80% of the window is on screen1 but the upper left corner is on screen 2, the maximized window will be on screen1.

Still, your idea is the best one. After over an hour of google (using QT5), I now use:

writeSettings:

```
settings.setValue("pos", pos());
if(!isMaximized())
    settings.setValue("size", size());
settings.setValue("maximized", isMaximized());
```

readSettings:

```
if(settings.contains("pos"))
    move(settings.value("pos").toPoint());
if(settings.contains("size"))
    resize(settings.value("size").toSize());

if(settings.value("maximized").toBool())
    setWindowState(windowState() | Qt::WindowMaximized);
```

Comment: I understand and I know how to achieve desired result (using something similar to your solution), but the whole point was: `saveGeometry` should release me from necessity to write all this code and just do the obvious thing itself. My question was: is it a bug, or is there some motivation behind such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're having is coming from a number of geometries and sizes being readable and set-able for a QWidget.  Specifically, you might want to look at the differences between normalGeometry, height, width, maximumHeight, maximumWidth, minimumHeight, minimumWidth etc.

Comment: My question restated in above terms: `QWidget::saveGeometry` doesn't store `normalGeometry`. Why not? Is there a reson not to? Seems useful to me. (min/max sizes are irrelevant here).